#2 Chinese Site Meeting
Here we will discuss about future Chinese Site meetings. If you want to read old transcripts for all of our meetings, check this discussion: Chinese Chat meetings transcripts

Keep checking this post for updates!



Duration: 1 hour
Structure (roughly): 

First 5 minutes: welcoming new users or new "entries" in the regulars;
45 minutes: we talk about the decided topics;
Last 10 minutes: recap and last-minute news (if any) and deciding the topics of the next Meeting.

Some rules: During these chat events, it'd be best if we kept the jokes/chit-chat to a minimum so we don't waste time and we actually solve problems. The usual rules abour proper behavior apply. 
Who: Anyone can participate, and actually, I wish all of you would join the event. It'd be a huge victory towards our final goal: graduation and the creation of a great site of Chinese.
When: Saturday, July 14th, 14:00 UTC.  Check here for the time in your zone.
Register here
(By registering, you'll get the reminders for the event, in case you intend to participate. Also, the corresponding time in your Time Zone is written there too.
How: The meeting will be organized as a free conversation, but remember: be polite and don't make unnecessary noise, the transcript will be saved!
Topics:

Promotion (and visits)
Challenge Weeks
... content is being added, you can propose new topics: post an answer!


JOIN THE EVENT! :)

I'd like to suggest weekly/monthly sessions (in chat or as a meta Q and A) for learning 成语 and 歇后语。 We can have users try to use the 成语/歇后语 flavor of the week/month in a short paragraph or sentence and have the users pick the best one.
